# Postgres: Updating rows based on aggregated value without returning duplicated lines

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table and I want to select rows that have are from the same hour. Since I want to lock them, I want to update another column and set a value `started` to `now()`.

I also want only a single group at a time, therefore the `LIMIT 1`.

```sql
with subq as (SELECT some_column, array_agg(timestamp) as timestamps, array_agg(id) as ids, hour FROM (
    SELECT *, date_trunc('hour', timestamp) as hour from some_table FOR UPDATE
) as inner_table GROUP BY some_column, hour LIMIT 1)

UPDATE some_table SET started = now() FROM subq WHERE some_table.id = any(subq.ids) 
RETURNING subq.some_column, subq.timestamps
```

This seems to work except it returns me one line per updated line. As I am only referring to `subq` in the `RETURNING`, these lines are duplicates.

Is there something I can do about it? I don't know whether my initial subquery and update need to be improved or if this is okay and I only need to find a way to suppress `RETURNING` except the first line.

Answer (score 0):

During writing the question, another solution came to my mind which seems to do the trick. Instead of `RETURNING` I could wrap the `UPDATE` into another subquery and then return the original subquery:

```sql
with subq as (SELECT some_column, array_agg(timestamp) as timestamps, array_agg(id) as ids, hour FROM (
    SELECT *, date_trunc('hour', timestamp) as hour from some_table FOR UPDATE
) as inner_table GROUP BY some_column, hour LIMIT 1),
update_subq as (
    UPDATE some_table SET started = now() FROM subq WHERE some_table.id = any(subq.ids) 
)
SELECT * FROM subq;
```